# Programmer searching for divergences in Excel spreadsheets. Am I doing someone else's job?

Tags: software-industry, job-description

I am officially a system analyst and developer. My boss, more often than not, comes to me with a problem like "your colleague downloaded the spreadsheet that displays which customers paid the monthly fee and I am not sure it is correct. You should stop all your activities and compare it with this other spreadsheet".

Should I, as the only developer/analyst in the company, do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say this is ordinary and normal at most small companies.  I certainly did much work like this at small companies and even sometimes at big companies like Lockheed where our local staff had no financial analysts available. Your job is to do what your boss asks you to do. If no one else has the analytical skill to figure out how to get the spreadsheet right, then it is up to you. Those spreadsheets tend to be the most critical parts of the how things are managed at many companies, so most bosses would consider this a high priority, urgent task.